# Group concat double results

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on an application that runs the following query:

```
SELECT m.*, GROUP_CONCAT(g.title) as genres
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN genre_movie gm ON gm.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN genre g ON gm.genre_id = g.id
WHERE m.imdb_id = '454876'
```

When I run the query in my query browser or straight via SSH it returns the following results  (example:)

[image]

In my PHP code I do the following to loop over the genres:

```
<?php $get =  mysql_query($query); // $query is the above query ?>
<?php $movieInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($get); ?>
<?php $genres = explode(",", $movieInfo['genres']); ?>
<?php foreach ($genres as $genre) { ?>
    <li class="clear"><a><span class="value"><?php echo $genre; ?></span></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

**While the expected out is expected to be:**

> Drama, Adventure

**The output is:**

> Drama, Drama, Drama, Adventure, Adventure, Adventure

Any idea why this is happening as I can't figure it out?

PS: I know a work-around would be to just add `array_unique()` when I explode the comma separated list of the genres but I want to know the root of the problem.

Basically when I run the query manually the genres show up fine, when it runs in the applications, it shows double while the rest of the info still shows just fine.

Comment: can we say the issue is mainly in your `PHP code` ?

Comment: Added the query and fetching of the result, don't know where it goes wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have forgotten **GROUP BY** clause in SQL, due to which duplicate records are written.

Comment: Still can't figure out why this was showing the correct results when I ran the exact same query via the terminal though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you grouping by the proper movie id? It could be the reason that you are getting all genres grouped into one..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, problem was with the query, I forgot to GROUP BY:

```
SELECT m.*, GROUP_CONCAT(g.title) as genres
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN genre_movie gm ON gm.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN genre g ON gm.genre_id = g.id
WHERE m.imdb_id = '454876' GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: oh darn thing.. I saw your row results where it has returned `Drama, Adventure`. So I removed my answer which was the `group by` ;)